# Formatting array in PHP for output to csv using fputcsv

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in this format:

[image: array]

That I want to output to csv.  The trouble I'm having is getting that array in the right format.  When I do:

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
   fputcsv($df, $row);
}
```

I only get the integer values.  I am missing a column with the names like `ACCESSORIES`.

Here is the output:

[image: csv]

But I want column A to have the names like `ACCESSORIES` and column B to have the values.

Comment: an off topic question but how did you get that pretty output in first screenshot?

Comment: Is the actual array is looking like the same as you send in the screenshort you can use the foreach($array as $key=>$value){
}

Comment: Why is your input array set up like that in the first place? Why not make it an ordinary associative array, `array('ACCESSORIES' => 0, 'ANNUALS' => 0, ...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fputcsv` just outputs the array values; the keys would usually be column names, not additional columns in the row. You need to make an array out of each element's key and value.

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $keys = array_keys($row);
    fputcsv($df, array($keys[0], $row[$keys[0]]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the iteration loop of foreach like that :

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
       fputcsv($df, array($key[0], $value[$key[0]]));
    }
```

Comment: This won't work. When you iterate over `$array`, `$key` will be indexes `0`, `1`, `2`, etc.

Comment: can you just display the array you want to iterate not the snap.

Comment: What do you mean by snap?

Comment: i mean to say full array that you want to iterate can you just show me that full array(13).

Comment: I can't, I'm not the OP. But It's obviously just more entries like the 6 that he showed in the screen grab.

Answer (score 1):

if somebody is looking for exporting the results from a query with dynamic headers to an array then to csv file you could use the following function :

```
function exportCSVFile($fieldsNames, $result)
{

$fileName = "result.csv";
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$stdout = fopen('php://output', 'w');

fputcsv($stdout, $fieldsNames, ',', '"'); // put the headers or fields Names

$resultArray = array();

$tempRowHolder = array();

/* 
    build the finalized array which will be used to export the result as csv 
*/

for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($fieldsNames); $j++) {
        $tempRowHolder[$j] = $result[$i][$fieldsNames[$j]]; // fetch a row by the different fields names
    }

    /* push the row from the tempRowHolder array to the main array($resultArray) */
    array_push($resultArray, $tempRowHolder);

    /* clear the temporary array (the holder of the row) to use it fresh in the next iteration */
    $tempRowHolder = [];
}

$i = 0;

/* put the finalized array into the csv file  */
while ($i < count($resultArray)) {
    fputcsv($stdout, $resultArray[$i++]);
}

fclose($stdout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it will help you ,I used my array like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NUMBER] => 67
            [TYPE] => Other
            [DATE] => 3/31/2011
        )
     [1] => Array
          (
            [NUMBER] => 87
            [TYPE] => something
            [DATE] => 3/28/2011


          )
     [2] => Array
          (
            [NUMBER] => 67
            [TYPE] => Other
            [DATE] => 3/2/2011


          )

)

<?php


$fp1 = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($arr2 as $fields) 
{
    fputcsv($fp1, $fields);
}

fclose($fp1);

?>
```